# Is this over optimisation of the <title> tag?

Tags: keywords, title, meta-keywords, title-attribute

I've got a page on a camera review site the page is as follows (below). Would you consider this over optimisation / keyword stuffing? Specifically in the title tag as it has 2 references to "canon 600d".

(domain name is fictional, also please ignore title tag length its just for illustration purposes)

---

domain name = bestcamerareviews.com/canon-600d-review

title tag = Canon 600d review - best camera reviews - Canon 600d pros and cons

H1 tag = Canon 600d review

has natural copy (natural keyword density)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider it over optimization to have "reviews" twice in the URL *and* twice in the title tag, and having "Canon 600d" twice in the title tag. (These days you're not really going to get additional mileage targeting "review" and "reviews" separately.) I would make each of those appear one time within each data type... I have no specific sources for this, just my opinion based on general things I've read about keyword stuffing and from my experience with SERPs.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation in my website.

As per my understanding excessive keyword stuffing in the title can lead to site displaying H1 tag instead of title tag and definitely will be penalized by Google in search results.

The site will continue to appear in the search results but way behind. So I will highly recommend to use descriptive title for your website that makes sense and doesn't looks like over optimized to robots. You need to create it from user perspective and not ranking perspective.